# Using Dictionaries instead of globals()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datareader

I am doing a business case on retrieving stock information. The teacher uses the code below to create DataFrames with stock information.

```
#The tech stocks we'll use for this analysis

tech_list = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT','AMZN']

#Set up End and Start times for data grab
end = datetime.now()

start = datetime(end.year - 1,end.month,end.day)

#For loop for grabing yahoo finance data and setting as a dataframe

for stock in tech_list: 
# Set DataFrame as the Stock Ticker
     globals()[stock] = DataReader(stock,'yahoo',start,end)
```

He uses `globals()` to create the 4 dataframes with the techstock. I read in the question below that you can also use dictionary to achieve the same goal.

[pandas set names of dataframes in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620014/pandas-set-names-of-dataframes-in-loop)

MY QUESTION is that i do not understand this line of code in the answer:

```
frames = {i:dat for i, dat in data.groupby('Sport')}
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: `globals()` is a dictionary

Comment: `frames` is a dictionary that is being built using a *comprehension*. The call `data.groupby()` is returning a pair of values, called `i` and `dat`, and the notation`{i:dat for i, dat in ...}` is building a new dictionary out of all such pairs, using `i` as the key and `dat` as the value.

Comment: You could also write it as `frames = dict(data.groupby('Sport'))`

Comment: @Z4-tier There's probably a canonical dup that explains what a dictionary comprehension is, but I don't have it in my list. You got one?

Comment: @Barmar I can't find one. Lots of questions that involve dictionary comprehensions, but I can't find something that *just* explains what it is. I'll post an answer and maybe someone else will come by with the link.

Comment: @Barmar I just use the list comprehension canonical one, the accepted answer explains them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `frames` is a dictionary that is being built using a *dictionary comprehension*. The call `data.groupby()` is returning a pair of values, which are being called `i` and `dat` in the comprehension, and the notation `{i:dat for i, dat in ...}` is building a new dictionary out of all such pairs, using `i` as the key and `dat` as the value. The result is stored in `frames`.

The general syntax is (for the case where the iterator returns 2 elements):

```
{key: value for key, value in iterator}
```

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator) do a good job explaining what an iterator is in python. Usually (but not always), when used in a dictionary comprehension, the iterator's `__next__()` method will return two elements. At least one of the elements must be hashable so that it can be used as the dictionary key.

`iterator` doesn't necessarily need to return two elements (although that is a common use pattern). [This works](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
print(dict([(i, chr(65+i)) for i in range(4)]))
{0 : 'A', 1 : 'B', 2 : 'C', 3 : 'D'}
```

and also shows that dictionary comprehensions are really just special syntax using same mechanics as *list comprehensions* and the `dict()` method, which is what the comment by @Barmar is doing:

```
frames = dict(data.groupby('Sport'))
```

In this case, `data.groupby()` **does** need to return two elements, and the order **does** matter, as it is shorthand for (roughly) this:

```
dict([(key, value) for key, value in data.groupby('Sport')])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Now i understand the logic behind a dictionary comprehension. Just one last doubt. 

The dataframe 'frame' in the example has 2 columns ('Sport' & 'random_data'). What if there would be another column 'player', so, the dataframe 'frame' has 3 columns. If i wanted to create a dictioanry comprehnesion to call only the columns 'Sport' and 'player', what would be the syntax in a dict comprehnesion? 

I tried the following but it does not work: 'frames = {i:dat for i in data.groupby('Sport'), dat in data['player'] }'

Comment: You could do something like this: `{sport: {player: player_stats for player, player_stats in sport_stats.groupby('player')} for sport, sport_stats in data.groupby('sport')}`. This uses a nested dictionary comprehension: since `sport_stats.groupby('sport')` returns pairs that look like `('sport', DataFrame)`, the inner comprehension will unpack the first DataFrame (which I called sport_stats), this time grouping by player, so you get `(sport, (player, player_DataFrame))`. This is a good example of why it is good to use meaningful names and not single letters :)